# Detecting a Pipewire Virtual Sink in Java

Tags: audio, java, pop-os, pipewire

I'm trying to set up a Virtual Sink using Pipewire which I've done successfully, however, I am having trouble detecting it in Java though other applications have no problem detecting it.

I can play audio to the sink when it is selected as the system default but whenever I call `AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();` it isn't included in the list of mixers.

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the systems or if there is a problem preventing it from being displayed.